# How can I achieve a photoshop "bevel / emboss" like depth effect using Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

I want to place an image on top of a background-image and apply a "bevel/emboss" effect on the image using Python. I made an attempt using the PIL library but suggestions for other libraries are welcome too.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

I have the following code:

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

img = Image.open('./image.jpeg', 'r')

# this doesn't do what I want...
img = img .filter(ImageFilter.EMBOSS)

background = Image.open('./bg.png', 'r')

background.paste(img)
```

I used Affinity Photo for the example image. Should be pretty much the same in Photoshop. Here are the settings I used:

[image]

Comment: Well this is my honest attempt at solving the problem. I searched stack overflow and other websites but I couldn't find anything useful. I looked at the PIL docs but they weren't helpful either. I don't have much experience with image processing, I don't even know what you would call this effect other than the name displayed in Photoshop/Affinity Photo. The EMBOSS filter of PIL is something completely different with a similar name so I didn't bother to post an image of it.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how I can do this in python but I found a way around it using a combination of the the batch job and the macro functionality in Affinity Photo.

1. record a macro that applies the desired effect to an image
2. place all images that need the effect in a folder
3. start a batch job and apply the macro to all images

How to start a batch job is described here: http://www.millermattson.com/blog/batch-processing-with-affinity-photo/

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when Googling trying to figure out how to bevel and emboss text with PIL. It take a couple hours of fussing with it but I'm pretty happy with the solution and wanted to share:

```
def draw_embossed_text(image, text, font, position, fill, highlight, shadow):
    """
    Create an embossed text effect on an image

    :param image: PIL Image object to write on
    :param text: The text to write
    :param font: The ImageFont for the text
    :param position: Tuple (x, y) of the position to write the text
    :param fill: The color of the text as an RGB tuple
    :param highlight: Highlight color as an RGB tuple
    :param shadow: Shadow color as an RGB tuple
    :return: Modified PIL Image object with embossed text
    """
    # Convert image to RGBA
    image = image.convert('RGBA')

    # Create text mask
    text_mask = Image.new('L', image.size, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_mask)
    draw.text(position, text, font=font, fill=255)

    # Create a layer for the fill color text
    fill_text_layer = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
    fill_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(fill_text_layer)
    fill_draw.text(position, text, font=font, fill=fill + (255,))

    # Apply emboss filter to the text mask
    embossed_mask = text_mask.filter(ImageFilter.EMBOSS)
    embossed_mask = ImageOps.autocontrast(embossed_mask).filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(3))

    # Create a layer for the embossed effect using the mask
    embossed_layer = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, fill + (0,))
    embossed_layer.putalpha(embossed_mask)

    # Convert embossed layer to NumPy array for pixel manipulation
    embossed_array = np.array(embossed_layer)
    alpha_channel = embossed_array[:, :, 3]

    # Determine highlight and shadow areas
    highlight_area = alpha_channel > 128
    shadow_area = alpha_channel < 128

    # Apply highlight and shadow
    embossed_array[highlight_area, :3] = highlight
    embossed_array[shadow_area, :3] = shadow

    # Adjust intensity
    intensity = np.minimum(np.minimum(np.abs(alpha_channel - 128), np.abs(128 - alpha_channel)) * 2, 255)
    embossed_array[:,:,3] = np.where(highlight_area | shadow_area, intensity, 0)

    # Convert back to PIL Image
    embossed_layer = Image.fromarray(embossed_array)
    
    # Composite the embossed text onto the original image
    image_with_text = Image.alpha_composite(image, fill_text_layer)
    final_image = Image.alpha_composite(image_with_text, embossed_layer)

    return final_image
```